# Can't use library functions inside a controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create my own library so i can handle custom areas in my application. i have a small library located at application/libraries which i called randomizer. it looks like this:

```
Class Randomizer { 
 public function __construct()
 {
   parent::_construct();
   $CI =& get_instance();
   $CI->load->library('session');
   $CI->load->database();
 }

 function test_function($name)
 {
    return 'Hi dear' . $name . 'welcome back!';
 }
}
```

In my Controller i tried to test out the simple test_function:

```
public function index()
{
    echo($this->Randomizer->test_function('John'));
    exit;
}
```

And I am getting the following error

```
Call to a member function test_function() on a non-object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of possible errors i can see. first you are not loading the library you created inside your controller. in case you don't use `$this->load->library('randomizer');` right before you call the library funcion. if you are going to use the library all over the controller then load it via the controller __consturct. Also i guess you are not extending an existing Class so the `parent::_construct()` is not needed. make sure you understand why you are using a library and when you should use helpers. Read more about [Codeigniter Libraries](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please look closely to the [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html). There are a few problems.

First of all it seems that you have either not loaded the library (`$this->load->library('randomizer')`), otherwise you would get a syntax error because your are calling `parent::_construct()`, instead of `parent::__construct`. And you do not have to call that function anyway, because your class doesn't have a parent (it doesn't `extend` a class...).

Furthermore, although you declare your class with a capital, the variable will be lowercase. So you should call `$this->randomizer->test_function()`